# Android: Перестал работать Room, после обновления до версии 2.4.3

Tags: android, android-room, room

Android: Перестала работать база данных Room, после обновления до версии 2.4.3. Приложение жалуется на AppDatabase_Impl, сгенерированный файл.

> AppDatabase_Impl.java:72: error: onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in
> <anonymous com.mobile_solutions.mycar.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1>
> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
> protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
> ^   attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Содержимое AppDatabase:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        Service::class,
        Profile::class,
        WorkItem::class,
        Auto::class,
        Recommendation::class,
        TechVisit::class,
        NotificationSimple::class,
        Expense::class
               ], version = 85, exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myCarDao(): MyCarDao?
}
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

> AppDatabase_Impl.java:72: error: onCreate(Support SQLite Database) in
> <anonymous com.mobile_solutions.mycar.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1>
> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
> protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
> ^ attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Что делать?

Comment: clean build делали?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508332/android-studio-attempting-to-assign-weaker-access-privileges-error-on-room-da